# Chinese Idiom puzzle 21 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

A new puzzle for July 2021

[image]

1. The hunter doesn't know he is being hunted
2. extremely foolish
3. 在水滸傳中的梁山泊排第一百零七位，綽號鼓上蚤的人物
4. If you want to deliberately frame others, you can always find excuses
5. Busy traffic
6. The sin is so evil, the end is here
7. Refund
8. 有關苻堅的故事. Describe what a huge army can do
9. Light of dawn
10. When encountering what should be done, take on the task without hesitation
11. Two things closely affecting each other; a close relationship between the two
12. Virtuous and honor
13. The road ahead is unclear
14. Anonymous
15. Refers to feeling ashamed of accepting certain gifts and rewards. Mostly used as a self-effacement
16. Can see but can't get close
17. The ideal relationship between brothers
18. Wastefully/freely spend
19. A few words and to the point
20. Observant
21. Virtuous and willing to spend money to help others
22. Acting arbitrarily, without considering the opinions of others
23. The truth comes out
24. 30 years old
25. Abandoned by everyone

A. Up against unstoppable power

B. There are previous examples that can serve as references

C. To probe and test the prospects

D. Hurry; speed up

E. Nothing to hide

F. Win back to back championship or election

G. At a loss, not understand at all

H. Moving non-stop like a river flow

I. 趙匡胤成為皇帝的故事

J. Performing calligraphy on the spot

K. Give and receive secretly

L. Great sin

M. Independent

N. Cannot speak out

O. 汉朝初年丞相

P. Worthy of the praise words or title

Q. Act arbitrarily, not listen to any opposition,

R. Ignorant

S. Step down and let the more capable man take the position

T. Good teachers and good friends

U. Turn against one's own family for justice

V. "Timely Rain" 水滸傳中宋江的其中一個綽號

W. Openly; Nothing to hide

X. Cantonese bless each other with this phrase in the Lunar New Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 螳螂捕蝉，黄雀在后
2. 愚不可及
3. 时迁
4. 欲加之罪，何患无辞
5. 车水马龙
6. 恶贯满盈
7. 退款
8. 投鞭断流
9. 晨光
10. 当仁不让
11. 息息相关
12. 贤良方正
13. 前路茫茫
14. 无名氏
15. 受之有愧
16. 可望而不可即
17. 兄友弟恭
18. 挥霍
19. 言简意赅
20. 明察秋毫
21. 仗义疏财
22. 独断专行
23. 水落石出
24. 而立
25. 众叛亲离

A. 螳臂当车

B. 前车可鉴

C. 投石问路

D. 快马加鞭

E. 光明磊落

F. 蝉联

G. 茫然不解

H. 川流不息

I. 黄袍加身

J. 即席挥毫

K. 私相授受

L. 罪大恶极

M. 独立

N. 有苦难言

O. 萧何

P. 当之无愧

Q. 一意孤行

R. 愚昧无知

S. 退位让贤

T. 良师益友

U. 大义灭亲

V. 及时雨

W. 光明正大

X. 恭喜发财

Comment: 9. 晨光 is morning light; 曙光 is light of dawn, I would accept either.  I  also accept N. 有苦难言 or 有口难言; From 16. 可望而不(可)即, you should get B. 前車(可)鉴